# \schemata in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, schemata

I can't export in org-mode to latex with `\schemata`.
It seems that it recognizes the header `\schemata` and the command `\schema` but when exporting to pdf it is not displayed.
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{schemata}

\long\def
\schema{\schemabox{main concept}}{\schemabox{first detail \\ second detail}}
```

Comment: Please don't spam this question demanding a MWE.

Comment: do you really have a blank line after `\long\def` in your source (which will lead to errors) or is that just an error in the markdown while posting to this site?

Comment: no, no blank space, it's a error

Comment: Are you saying that *orgmode* highlights the syntax of `\schemata` and `\schema` by the word *recognizes*? *orgmode* could be doing that automatically [things after the `\something` ] or know it is a TeX command, and you are right :)

Comment: If you look at what the export tex file contains you will see the braces `{...}` are changed to `\{...\}`.  You need to tell org mode that this is to be interpreted as latex code.  Use either `#+LATEX: code` or an export block for this.